# Can't Install shadcn-ui with next.js 13.4.9

Tags: next.js

FetchError: request to https://ui.shadcn.com/registry/styles/index.json failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 76.76.21.9:443
at ClientRequest. (file:///D:/Projects/WebProjects/Ecommerce/my-app/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
type: 'system',
errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
erroredSysCall: 'connect'
}
Failed to fetch styles from registry.

I've tried
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy

and didn't work out

Comment: what command are you running to install?

Comment: I got the same error using `npx shadcn-ui@latest init`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hi, did you find a way to fix this? Im getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems shadcn has blocked your region, and by setting a vpn server you could get this problem fixed.For me it works in this way.

1- set a vpn server

2- make sure it works well

3 run `npx shadcn-ui@latest add [any-component]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run "npm run dev" first to load the next folder. Then install the shadcn component. It should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it's look like unreachable site problem. probably shadcn website blocked your origin.
use proxy application and run npx.

Answer (score 0):

Your region is probably blocked by shadcn. I also had this problem and changed the proxy and was able to install it. If you use a proxy, test different regions.